# jQuery/CSS: Making the autocomplete push other divs down?

Tags: jquery, css, tags

I'm using the xoxco jQuery tagsystem for tags and their autocompletesystem for the.. wait for it...autocomplete! http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

I then stylize this list by modifying three different classes in CSS:

```
ui-autocomplete
ui-menu-item
ui-corner-all
```

Right below this tagwindow i have some other content and my problem is that when the autocomplete list appears below the tag input, the content below doesn't move down which makes the autocomplete appear above that.

**ADDED:**

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jQm2C/1/show/
What I want is to place the autocomplete list inside the  tags. Or any type of tags that I want to. Especially between div or span tags.

How can I solve this?

**ADDED #2:**

After some research in jQuery I think I can further explain what I want to do. I want to append the , which is the autocompletelist, to a div. Though I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Do you have jquery-ui css added ?

Comment: Just added it and the box looks way better. ;P Though I still got the same problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: you have to mess with z-index if you are talking about changing what is in front - I'm not sure what you mean by on top and bottom -  if it is other stuff below that is getting hidden , that stuff below should be positioned relative , and it will move when the contents above it expands

Comment: Yes, I want the content below to move when the content anor expands. The problem is that the taglist is among all the top divs if you look in devmode in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed it! http://jsfiddle.net/jQm2C/7/show/

What I did was to append the "top class" of the autocomplete list `.ui-autocomplete` to a div named `.test` using this jQuery code:

```
$('.test').append($('.ui-autocomplete'));
```

Then to style the list I wrote this CSS. For some reason I can't put the CSS in the CSS box without making the thing stop working:

```
.ui-autocomplete{
    position: static !important;
    float:none !important;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: That's great! I wasn't getting anywhere fast haha. If you really want a lot of implementation you might have to make your own (not in your case atm) Good luck

Comment: Yeah, well I will see where I can go with this and if I run into a problem that I really can't solve then I will probably make some sort of function on my own :) But for now this is great! Thanks for your help anyway. :D